# Branchio Universal Deeplink redirecting to safari and shows popup to launch the application even app is installed in iOS 13.3.1

Tags: safari, ios13, branch.io, deeplink, ios13.3

Even though the Application is installed in the iPhone, tapping **Branchio** universal deep-link redirecting to safari and shows a popup to launch the application.

**Expected: if the application is already installed, tapping deep link should launch the application.**

*Pre- requests:*

**OS: iPhone iOS 13.3.1**

1. Release build in Appcenter
2. Set custom URL to https://install.appcenter.ms/app (Appcenter)
3. Generate the Universal deeplink

*Steps to reproduce:*

1. Generate the Universal deep-link
2. Using the  deep-link install the application
3. Again Tap on the same deep-link will redirect to Safari and popup alert with CANCEL and OPEN options
4. Tap OPEN in safari to launch the application

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behaviour where Apple prompts the user first time if to open the app. Only if universal links are implemented, it does not ask for the second time. Our AASA validator tool (https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) shows the AASA file to validated correctly but while testing on the install page of your redirected website, it is showing a 404 error. So, we are unable to replicate this on our end to check further.

Could you please share your app store link so as to help us out here.

Also, would request to check our documentation here ( https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-troubleshooting#section-validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded ) so as to confirm if the device is receiving the generated AASA files. This is a known issue with Apple for iOS 13.x+ where the AASA files do not get ingested into the device and causes the link redirection to show a prompt or a fail.

Comment: Every time we are getting the popup, that shouldn't be the case right? from 2nd time onwards after the application is installed, the link should redirect to the app without opening the Safari. @promit.dey